# how to put char * argv[] to global variable

Tags: c

I am just trying to write something like that:

```
u64 get_env(char *argv[]);

char* g_argv[];

static char * Sample ()
{
  return (char*)get_env(g_argv);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   g_argv = argv;
   Sample();
}
```

> ```
> Getting error: 'g_argv' has an incomplete type
>
> warning: array 'g_argv' assumed to have one element [enabled by default]
> ```

I've tried many different ways. How to write it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Despite what it looks like, argv is not an array; arrays aren't first class objects in C and cannot be passed to functions, only their addresses can. So because argv is a parameter, it's actually a pointer to a pointer. For this reason I think it's better to tell the truth and use

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

which is exactly equivalent to the above. This confusion in the language has led you to

```
char* g_argv[];
```

You're saying this is an array of pointers, without saying how big the array is, but that's not what you want; you want a pointer to the first of several pointers:

```
char** g_argv;
```

That fixes the problem you asked about, but I wonder about this declaration:

```
u64 get_env(char *argv[]);
```

Why declare it as returning u64 when the name and usage clearly indicate that it returns a `char*`? Actually, you should not be declaring it here at all ... it should be declared in a header file that specifies the API that includes get_env. Hopefully that header file declares it as returning a `char*`, and then you can remove the cast from

```
return (char*)get_env(g_argv);
```

Comment: sorry, i've tried char ** g_argv; i've got error next and thought that cast has not working. Yes it is in header file, I just moved it here, so you could see and u64 is ok I think (not my code), it can result different types, for different arguments. In any case thank you for clarifiying.

Answer (score 4):

The compiler sees you declaring `g_argv` as an array of char pointers, but you don't specify how many.